# Context to be instantiated within the repository (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have Mobile area and Account controller in it

Here is code

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    private AccountRepositoryEntities repoEntities; //The desktop trackerweb repository
    private Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository mobileRepo;
    private IdentityUserManager userManager;
    private IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private Dictionary dictionary;

    public AccountController(TraxgoDB context) : base()
    {
        repoEntities = new AccountRepositoryEntities();
        mobileRepo = new Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository(context);
    }
}
```

Context is passed to controller.

I need  context to be instantiated within the repository

So controller will be like

```
public AccountController() : base()
{
    repoEntities = new AccountRepositoryEntities();
    mobileRepo = new Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository();
}
```

Here is code of `Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository`

```
public sealed class AccountRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public AccountRepository(TraxgoDB context) : base(context) { }

    public Site TryGetCustomSite(string hostName)
    {
        var site = context.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => hostName.Contains(s.HostName));
        if (site != null && site.HostName != "traxgo")
            return site;
        return null;
    }

    public CultureInfo UpdateCustomerLanguage(int customerID, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TraxgoDB(TraxgoDBRights.ReadWrite))
        {
            var customer = ctx.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == customerID);
            var currentCultureInfo = customer.Language.GetCultureInfo();

            if (currentCultureInfo != culture)
            {
                customer.Language = culture.GetLanguage();
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            return culture;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is BaseRepository

```
 public abstract class BaseRepository
{
    protected TraxgoDB context { get; }

    protected BaseRepository(TraxgoDB context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Without arguments. How I can do this?

**UPDATE**

In task was said

> each controller constructor with arguments, should have its argumentts
>   removed for example: public AccountController(TraxgoDB context)  ->
>   public AccountController()    mobileRepo = new
>   Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository(context);  -> mobileRepo =
>   new Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository();  because we want the
>   context to be instantiated within the repository

I think it needed to write it like this in controller?

```
public AccountController() : base()
    {
        using (TraxgoDB ctx = new TraxgoDB())
        {   
             repoEntities = new AccountRepositoryEntities();
             mobileRepo = new Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository(ctx);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably looking for something like this, which also introduces dependency injection. But then we are not instantiating, rather we are injecting.

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IAccountRepository _accountRepository;
    public AccountController(IAccountRepository accountRepository)
    {
        _accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }
}

public interface IAccountRepository
{
    Site TryGetCustomSite(string hostName);
     CultureInfo UpdateCustomerLanguage(int customerID, CultureInfo culture);
}

public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository, BaseRepository
{
    private readonly ITraxgoDB _context;

    public AccountRepository(ITraxgoDB context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Site TryGetCustomSite(string hostName)
    {
        var site = _context.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => hostName.Contains(s.HostName));
        if (site != null && site.HostName != "traxgo")
            return site;
        return null;
    }

    public CultureInfo UpdateCustomerLanguage(int customerID, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TraxgoDB(TraxgoDBRights.ReadWrite))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using .net core, then you can use the depeneny injection that is provided. Otherwise, if you use .netframeworks 4.x then you could consider something like autofac.

Comment: I use MVC5

So as I understood, I can use this code without any packages?

Comment: Correct, .net core has dependency injection. It should be configured in the middleware, startup.cs. Ie; services.AddScoped<ITraxgoDB, TraxgoDB>();

Comment: And also as I understood `public class AccountController : BaseController` is for controller and other code is for repository file?

Comment: I am not really sure what you ask. AccountController in this case implements from BaseController. I suppose BaseController implements from Controller and has some default configuration like [Authorize] and [AutoValidateAntiForgeryToken], but that is just assumption. This has nothing todo with dependency injection. This is just extending some base functionality into actual usage of the controller. Something similar is probably true for the repository.

Comment: Look I try your code and have an error. `BaseRepository ` - base class must be come before any interfaces

Comment: Well, the piece of code is only a small example in the bigger whole. So the best thing to do is to dive in the theory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154624/discussion-between-mark-spencer-and-bob-meijwaard).